# how to get the data from the row of a Tableview of JAVA Fx 2.0

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-2

Hello iam using this code to get the data

```
Set<Account> selection =new HashSet<Account>table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

But iam getting this as output

```
passbookprintingdemo.AccountPage$Account@1eb5170
```

can any one explain me how do i get the data instead of this class name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().YourGetterFunctionName `

and you will get your data :)

Answer (score 7):

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().YourGetterFunctionName and you will get your data :)
```